# Flutter: Resource linking failed

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting this error alter connecting my flutter app to the firebase. I dont know whats the reason  but I am getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 What went wrong:
Execution
     failed for task :app:process Debug Resources.
     Android resource linking failed
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was getting this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources'.
```

with follwing error :

```
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  Output:  D:\flutter\dashboard_app\dashboad_app\build\google_sign_in\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:197: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not f
ound.
  D:\flutter\dashboard_app\dashboad_app\build\google_sign_in\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:198: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

So i updated my google_sign_in sdk to : `google_sign_in 4.0.1+1` from [google_sdk](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in#-installing-tab-)